# How to start a Storyboard in a ControlTemplate of a Custom Button Style with CaliburnMicro?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro, controltemplate

I have a custom button style I built in Expression blend. I am using Caliburn Micro and want to be able to turn the FlashSafetyButton storyboard on and off from the viewModel for a button.

It seems like there should be an obvious way to do this but I'm missing it. I was thinking maybe I could make a custom VisualState and control that but it seems even less clear how to do that.

Maybe someone could show me how to use triggers for this?

In view

```
<Button x:Name="PopulateRuns" Content="Search for Runs within Range" Margin="5" Style="{DynamicResource SafetySystemButton}"  >
```

In style

```
 <ResourceDictionary...>
        <Style x:Key="SafetySystemButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                            ***<Storyboard x:Key="FlashSafetyButton">
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames RepeatBehavior="Forever" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Offset)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0.25"/>
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="1"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>***
                        </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Grid>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                        ...
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                        <Storyboard>...</Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" StrokeThickness="0" MinWidth="70" MinHeight="70">
                                <Ellipse.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF5C5A5A" Offset="0.208"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Ellipse.Fill>
                            </Ellipse>
                            <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="1" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" StrokeThickness="0" Fill="#FF5BA5B4" MinWidth="60" MinHeight="60"/>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="1" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" StrokeThickness="0" MinWidth="60" MinHeight="60">
                                <Ellipse.Fill>
                                    <RadialGradientBrush>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFCFDFD"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#7F236172" Offset="1"/>
                                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                                </Ellipse.Fill>
                            </Ellipse>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
                            <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True"/>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <!-- Resource dictionary entries should be defined here. -->
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: In `ControlTemplate.Triggers` use `EventTrigger` to start a storyboard. HTH

Comment: Used this: [WPF Tutorials](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/trigger-datatrigger-event-trigger/) helped a lot but ended up binding to the opacity 1 v .99 lame but I'm not sure how to setup a custom property to bind to.